# Wait for async download to be completed

Tags: c#, download

This is my whole source code. I want to download x files (lets assume we now have 2 files we want to download).

My main Point is to wait for all Downloads to complete and then proceed. 
I tried several points.

Task.WhenAll(List) -> Not working in my way of implementation

await -> impossibly in MainWindow function without async.

Workflow should be the following. 
Download started -> All Files Downloaded -> Show the Debug.Print

Atm: Source Code Output is ->
All Downloads done
"Download completed"
"Download completed"

Should be:
"Download completed"
"Download completed"
All Downloads done

Working for hours and no tiny step further to solve the problem. It is a WPF Application.

```
    private volatile bool _download_completed;
    public bool DownloadCompleted { get { return _download_completed; } }


    public MainWindow()
    {

        InitializeComponent();
        ProcessService.FillProcessData();
        ProcessService.CloseAllProcesses();
        DownloadHelper.AddDownloadFiles();

        foreach(KeyValuePair<string,Uri> file in DownloadHelper.DownloadFiles)
        {
            DownloadFile(file.Key, file.Value);
        }
        Debug.Print("All Downloads done.");

    }
```

---

```
  private void DownloadFile(string Filename, Uri Uri)
    {

        Console.WriteLine(Filename + " " + Uri);
        _download_completed = false;
        WebClient client = new WebClient();
        client.DownloadFileCompleted += new AsyncCompletedEventHandler(DownloadFileCompleted);
        client.DownloadProgressChanged += new DownloadProgressChangedEventHandler(DownloadProgressCallback);
        client.DownloadFileTaskAsync(Uri, Filename);

    }
```

---

```
private void DownloadProgressCallback(object sender, DownloadProgressChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.Dispatcher.Invoke(() => {

            progressBar.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
            StatusLabel.Content = e.ProgressPercentage + " % complete... ( " + e.BytesReceived + " / " + e.TotalBytesToReceive + ")";
        });
    }
```

---

```
    private void DownloadFileCompleted(object sender, AsyncCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Download completed");
        this.Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
        {
            StatusLabel.Content = "Download Finished";
        });

        _download_completed = true;

    }


}
```

Comment: Is there a particular reason you are using `WebClient` rather than `HttpClient`?

Comment: No, except of no knowledge

Comment: I'd suggest switching to `HttpClient`. Also, check out https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.whenall?view=netframework-4.7.2 .

Comment: Thanks i´ll have a look at HTTPClient.
I already had a look at the page you posted but i will again have a look :)
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use tasks to achieve this

First make your download function `async`:

```
    private async TaskDownloadFile(string Filename, Uri Uri)
        {
    
            Console.WriteLine(Filename + " " + Uri);
            _download_completed = false;
            WebClient client = new WebClient();
            client.DownloadFileCompleted += new AsyncCompletedEventHandler(DownloadFileCompleted);
            client.DownloadProgressChanged += new DownloadProgressChangedEventHandler(DownloadProgressCallback);
         
      await   client.DownloadFileTaskAsync(Uri, Filename);
    
        }
```

Make the method `async` and `await` the `DownloadFileTaskAsync` method.

I would suggest to remove the events for `DownloadFileCompeted` and `DownloadProgressChanged` if you will do multiple downloads they don't make much sense.

Now that you have made the method `async` do the following:

```
var file1DownloadTask = TaskDownloadFile("filename","url");
var file2DownloadTask = TaskDownloadFile("filename","url");
```

At this point your have two tasks:

You can use the `Task.WaitAll(list_of_taks_goes_here)`

```
Task.WaitAll(file1DownloadTask,file2DownloadTask )
```

The `wait` all method will wait for all the tasks to finished so the next line of code is called after those two tasks have finished:

Then you can do change the UI or whatever you need to do after the `Task.WaitAll` line:

You could also do the following:

```
await TaskDownloadFile("filename","url");
await TaskDownloadFile("filename2","url");
```

Which will wait for the downloads to finish before moving on to next line but this way you have to know all the files at the time your write the code, with the first method you could have a list of files from which you could build the tasks and pass them to `Task.WaitAll`.

Answer (score 1):

Please note that the below will download the full download into memory, if the files being downloaded are very large consider re-writing to call the GetStreamAsync on HttpClient instead and stream to file, but this will do for reasonable sizes.

You generally want to re-use HttpClient, but dispose when done, so if this is WPF you could construct and keep around on startup and dispose at end, but this is probably also reasonable.

Edit: Note you may want to do this on another thread and dispatch completion back in case locking the UI thread is an issue when this is happening.

```
void Main()
{
    using (var client = new HttpClient())
    {
        var tasks = new List<Task>();
        var files = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        files.Add("c:\\temp\\MyFilename1.md", "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/master/README.md");
        files.Add("c:\\temp\\MyFilename2.md", "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/master/README.md");

        foreach (var file in files)
        {
            tasks.Add(DownloadFileAsync(client, file.Key, file.Value));
        }

        Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray());
    }
}

async Task DownloadFileAsync(HttpClient client, string filename, string url)
{
    var contents = await client.GetStringAsync(url);
    File.WriteAllText(filename, contents);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. There is only  question. 
async is not allowed for MainWindow(), so await is not useable in this function.

Comment: @Exitare See Edited version, that help?

Comment: hmm, 
i got the following exception message:
Exception raised: "System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException" in mscorlib.dll.
Files are not downloaded. Is this a solution for a wpf app?
VS 17

Comment: @Exitare forgot to change Task.WhenAll to Task.WaitAll, my bad

Comment: Ok, i‘ll try tomorrow. But I think I rally really really misunderstood the wpf.

Comment: The part where you kick off DownloadFileTaskAsync is not blocking. It will start the process only. The DownloadFileCompleted event will be raised when either one of those files completes downloading, so you would have to wait with outputting your text until all files have been received. The DownloadFileAsync method I provided "kinda" does the same thing. It will ask for a download to be started and return controll to the caller (the foreach loop in this case), then schedule another, return, but the Task.WaitAll will then block. If this takes a while doing this in the ctor may not be great.

Answer (score 0):

> My main Point is to wait for all Downloads to complete and then proceed.

I encourage you to take a step back and consider the UX design of your application. It's *never* a good idea to wait for I/O and block the UI thread while doing so.

In particular, your ViewModel constructors should never *block* on I/O. ViewModel constructors should complete immediately and synchronously, so that your UI can be shown immediately and synchronously.

Now, a constructor may *start* asynchronous operations; that's fine. It just shouldn't wait for them to complete. Your constructor should initialize the ViewModel into a state that says "Downloading..." or something, and when the downloads complete (or as they progress), the ViewModel can *update* its state to reflect that.

For more information on this pattern, see my MSDN article on [data binding to asynchronous operations](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn605875.aspx).

Comment: Yeah you are totally right. And that’s the point. There was a terrible mistake of my design and thoughts how the app should work!